# Multiple Inheritance, Which method will be called?

Tags: java

```
interface A{
    public abstract void method();    
}

interface B{
    public abstract void method();    
}

class C implements A,B{
    public void method(){}

    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        C ob=new C();
        ob.method();

        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

in this case method() is called of which interface.

Comment: And now you can understand why you can `implement` multiple interfaces, but not `extend` multiple classes

Comment: there is no need for the *abstract* keyword here. Interface methods are by default public and abstract (meant to be overridden by contract)

Answer (score 1):

```
 C obj = new C();
```

`C`s method will be called

because it is `C`'s instance

*note: interface doesn't have implementation (atleast in this example)*

Comment: but method() is called of which interface?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: means the method method() is used of which interface its of A or B?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. An interface does not provide an implementation. The method called will be that declared and implemented in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that does not matter(Interface contain method definition) And fact is runtime it will invoke `class C`'s `method` declaration(`obj.method()`).

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method in an interface you don't provide a method body. You only define a prototype and a contract that all implementers must follow. This allows the compiler to know that if an Object implements an interface it must have those methods. Since you are not creating a method body in the two interfaces there is only one method which is found in class C.

This does not hold true for Java 1.8 where you can provide default implementations of methods in interfaces. Now you could have a similar case to your posted example where you implement two interfaces with conflicting method bodies. I say could because the designers foresaw this and it is a compiler error if you do not explicitly override conflicting default methods.

**Example:**

```
public class Main {

    public static interface A {

        default public int get() {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public static interface B {

        default public int get() {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public static class C implements A, B {

        public int get() {
            return B.super.get();
        }

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println( new C().get() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This an example of **multiple inheritance of types** it mean your class C and by used with A or B references.(this not  multiple inheritance of behaviors/methods or multiple inheritance of states), there is no **multiple inheritance of states** in Java

So you need to provide explicit implementation for this method to implement to the contact, remember **interface is a contract** and your class should implement that contract completelty (there is no inheritance of methods here).

but in Java 8 you could have **multiple inheritance of behaviors/methods** by providing **default** implementations in your interfaces, so if this the case, you will need to provide explicit implementation on the C class and you could delegate the call to one of the types. for example :

```
// delegate the call to A method implementation, Java 8 
@Override
public void method() { 
   A.super.method() 
}
```